# Retrieving image from database using Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to read image from database with Ajax, but I could not read the `xmlhttp.responseText` to the img src. The image is saved as binary data in database and also retrieved as binary data. I'm using Ajax in JSP, because I want to give the user the ability to upload images and I will view the last uploaded image, on mouse over action the Ajax will be activated and get the image back, the problem is in reading the img from the response.

This is the Ajax function:

```
function ajaxFunction(path) {
    if (xmlhttp) { 
        var s = path;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", s, true); 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        var Image = document.getElementById(Image_Element_Name);
        document.getElementById(Image_Element_Name).src = "data:" + xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

I also got exception in the server:

```
10415315 [TP-Processor1] WARN core.MsgContext  - Error sending end packet
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.send(ChannelSocket.java:537)
    at org.apache.jk.common.JkInputStream.endMessage(JkInputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.jk.core.MsgContext.action(MsgContext.java:302)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:183)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.finish(Response.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
10415316 [TP-Processor1] WARN common.ChannelSocket  - processCallbacks status 2
```

Comment: Can't you just set the src attribute of the image to point to a URL that gets you the image data? Is there really a reason you're using "ajax"?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? It is very difficult to imagine what you have done and how you have done it and come up with suggestions.

Comment: Cripes, stop using "ajax" just because the cool kids use it... there's no point in using XHR here.

Comment: ok then how i can trigger request for the jsp file that read the image on mouse over action?
i tried to use the attribute 
myimage.src="get_image.jsp?...."
i get the image once and when it changed in DB by user upload , the action mouse over again should request the jsp file again and change the img src , but that would not happen

Comment: @ama: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841730/use-ajax-to-reload-captcha

Comment: oh thnx the problem solved ,"The browser is just loading the image for you when it detects the new source" , i was just need to insert time to the request of jsp page : 


Image.src='get_image.jsp?s='+(new Date()).getTime();

Answer (score 2):

Why are you storing the images in the DB?
Save them as files and save the URL in the DB.

That way you can use AJAX to call a PHP that will read the DB, pull out the URL for the image and return it to you, so you can do something like:

```
img = document.getElementById("myimage");
img.src = URL; // where URL will contain the URL you got from the AJAX call
```

Comment: I don't want to use files , and I'm restrict with using AJAX and JSP files

Comment: May I ask why? Interesting discussion on saving in the filesystem vs the DB http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/9091.htm

Comment: As suggested before I think it's best to just set the src to the URL that fetches you the image. This also avoids having a lot of code that just gets an image from a URL!

Comment: because i want to be able to get the old images for each user any time i want

Comment: Storing them as files won't prevent you from doing that.

Comment: yes i know , but as i said i need to go with this way , there is any suggestion how to get the src from the response ??

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way how it works. As answered before, you basically just need to change the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element to a different URL. The webbrowser will then reload the image itself automagically.

In case of JSP/Servlet, the URL should just point to a `Servlet` class which obtains an `InputStream` of the image from the database and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the response the usual Java IO way along with a set of response headers.

Here is how your Javascript instead should look like:

```
function changeImage(newSrc) {
    document.getElementById(Image_Element_Name).src = newSrc;
}
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/retrieve-multiple-images-from-mysql/2341322#2341322) you can find a complete example how the `Servlet` should look like.

---

The `SocketException: broken pipe` is just a sign that the client side didn't process the response at all and aborted it. If you get rid of that Ajax stuff and do it as explained above, then it should work flawlessly.

Comment: yes I see ,that is what I did for obtain the image from DB the problem was in sending the request for the jsp file ,when I add the time as parameter to the request ,the browser found new request each time ,so there will be new src for the image and the browser will load the image.

Comment: Ah OK. You're welcome. I however see that you're new here. You are supposed to vote the useful answers (click the up arrow) and accept the most helpful answer (click the checkmark). Also see this link to learn how Stackoverflow works: http://stackoverflow.com/faq :)